# Input.KeyDown() returns error but Input.GetKeyDown() does not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a weird problem.  I'm trying to make an object move in the direction you press for as long as you hold that button. When I use Input.GetButton(), I get an error that the direction I use ("left," "right," "up," or "down") is not defined, but it is defined.  If I use Input.GetKeyDown() instead, everything compiles as usual.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovementHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {

//      if (Input.GetButton ("left")) //Does Not work
//          Debug.Log ("left");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("left")) //Works
            Debug.Log ("left");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u show the definitions of `left`,`right`,`up`,`down`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input.GetButton and Input.GetKeyDown take two different inputs.

Input.GetKeyDown checks to see if the key "left" is being pressed. That being said, the documentation says you should be using a KeyCode object as your parameter, like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) // reads the left arrow key
```

(See [GetKeyDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) and [KeyCode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) docs.)

Input.GetButton is expecting to check to see if a Button object with the specified name is being pressed.

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) //reads the CTRL key
```